# Bash script command handler to replace long if chain

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a bunch of if statements with the form:

if (some flag variable/argument is set) then
  execute another command or bash script

This is a bit troublesome to maintain, so I was wondering if there was some other way of doing this. While this [guide](https://discordjs.guide/#/command-handling/dynamic-commands) is for node.js, I was wondering if it is possible to achieve something similar in bash

Comment: Use bash associative arrays. Google it.

Comment: This is much easier if you design your other scripts to be named according to your subcommands or conditions. Look at how `git` does it: When you run `git foo ...`, it looks for a command named `git-foo`; that way, it doesn't have a hardcoded list of subcommands (no `if` chain needed!), but just looks for any command that exists with your subcommand as a suffix.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Can you give an example of such a command?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a wrapper function that checks the variable and then executes the command passed in:

```
#!/bin/bash

run_if_set() {
    local var=$1
    shift
    (($# == 0)) && return   # nothing to run
    [[ $var ]] && "$@"      # execute only if var is set to a non-empty string
}
```

Then replace your if statements with:

```
run_if_set "$var" command ...
```

which is slightly more readable than

```
if [[ $var ]]; then
  command ...
fi
```

or

```
[[ $var ]] && command ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you're looking for something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# initialize global options 
debug=false
verbose=0

main() {
    local OPTIND
    while getopts :hdv: opt; do
        case $opt in
            h) show_help; exit ;;
            d) debug=true ;;
            v) verbose=$OPTARG;;
            :) echo "error: missing argument for -$OPTARG"; exit 1;;
            ?) echo "error: unknown option -$OPTARG"; exit 1 ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND-1))
    if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
        echo "error: missing subcommand"
        show_help
        exit 1
    fi
    case $1 in
        bar|baz) 
            # invoke the command with the arguments
            "$@" ;;
        *) echo "error: unknown subcommand $1"; exit 1;;
    esac
}

show_help() {
    echo "usage: $(basename "$0") [global opts] subcommand [local opts and args]"
    echo "... more details..."
}

bar() {
    echo "you called $FUNCNAME with args $*"
}

baz() {
    echo "this is baz"
    local OPTIND
    while getopts :ab opt; do
        case $opt in
            a|b) echo "you selected option $opt";;
            ?) echo "unknown option -$OPTARG";;
        esac
    done
    if $debug; then echo "some debug message"; fi
    (( verbose > 0 )) && echo "some verbose message"
}

main "$@"
```